# How to implement VGA Controller for Changing Background Color in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, vga

I'm a beginner VHDL coder. For just fun, I'm trying to implement the `640x480 @60Hz` VGA controller with Basys 2 Spartan-3E FPGA Trainer Board. My goal is to make background-color other than black and put 2 rectangles with a different color compared to the background. However, what I obtained is as follows:
[image]

One of the problem is that basys 2 has a clock jitter. Because of this problem, rectangles have a horizontal shift.  https://www.reddit.com/r/FPGA/comments/1hf4fb/dealing_with_clock_jitter/
Why does not the background-color change?

The simulation result as follows:
[image]

The related part of the VHDL code as follows:

```
draw: process(clk25,RST,hPos,vPos,videoOn)
begin
    if(RST = '1') then
        RGB <= "00000000";
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 ='1') then

        if(videoOn <= '1') then
            if((hPos>=10 and hPos <=60) AND (vPos>=10 and vPos <=60) )then
                RGB <= "11111111";

            elsif((hPos>=70 and hPos <= 120) AND (vPos>=10 and vPos <=60 ) )then
                RGB <= "11111110";
            else
                RGB <= "00000011";  
            end if;
        else
            RGB <= "00000000";
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

The whole code as follows:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity vga_driver is
    Port ( CLK   : in  STD_LOGIC;
           RST   : in  STD_LOGIC;
           HSYNC : out  STD_LOGIC;
           VSYNC : out  STD_LOGIC;
           RGB   : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end vga_driver;

architecture Behavioral of vga_driver is

signal clk25 : std_logic := '0';

constant HD  : integer := 639;  -- Horizontal Display
constant HFP : integer := 16;   -- Right border (front)
constant HSP : integer := 96;     -- Sync pulse (retrace)
constant HBP : integer := 48;   -- Left border (back    porch)

constant VD  : integer := 479;  -- Horizontal Display
constant VFP : integer := 10;   -- Right border (front)
constant VSP : integer := 2;      -- Sync pulse (retrace)
constant VBP : integer := 33;   -- Left border (back    porch)

signal hPos: integer := 0;
signal vPos: integer := 0;

signal videoOn: std_logic := '0';
signal frameCounter: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);


begin

clk_div: process(CLK)
begin
    if(CLK'event and CLK = '1')then
        clk25 <= not clk25;
    end if ;
end process;

Horizontal_pos_counter:process(clk25,RST)
begin
    if(RST = '1') then 
        hPos <= 0;
    elsif(clk25 'event and clk25 = '1')then
        if(hPos = HD + HFP + HSP + HBP) then
            hPos <= 0; 
        else
            hPos <= hPos +1;
        end if;
    end if ;
end process;


Vertical_pos_counter:process(clk25,RST,hPos)
begin
    if(RST = '1') then 
        vPos <= 0;
    elsif(clk25 'event and clk25 = '1')then
        if(hPos = (HD + HFP + HSP + HBP))then
            if(vPos = (VD + VFP + VSP + VBP)) then
                vPos <= 0; 
                if(frameCounter < "1111111111111111") then
                    frameCounter <= frameCounter+1;
                else
                    frameCounter <= (others => '0') ;
                end if;
            else
                vPos <= vPos +1;

            end if;
        end if;
    end if ;
end process;

Horizontal_Synchronisation:process(clk25,RST,hPos)
begin
    if(RST = '1') then
        HSYNC <= '0';
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 = '1') then
        if((hPos <= (HD + HFP)) OR (hPos > (HD + HFP + HSP)))then
            HSYNC <= '1';
        else
            HSYNC <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

Vertical_Synchronisation:process(clk25,RST,hPos)
begin
    if(RST = '1') then
        VSYNC <= '0';
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 = '1') then
        if((vPos <= (VD + VFP)) OR (vPos > (VD + VFP + VSP))) then
            VSYNC <= '1';
        else
            VSYNC <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;

end process;

video_on: process(clk25,hPos,vPos,RST)
begin
    if(RST = '1') then
        videoOn <= '0';
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 ='1') then
        if(hPos <= HD and vPos <= VD) then
            videoOn <= '1';
        else
            videoOn <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;

end process;

draw: process(clk25,RST,hPos,vPos,videoOn)
begin
    if(RST = '1') then
        RGB <= "00000000";
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 ='1') then

        if(videoOn <= '1') then
            if((hPos>=10 and hPos <=60) AND (vPos>=10 and vPos <=60) )then
                RGB <= "11111111";
            elsif((hPos>=70 and hPos <= 120) AND (vPos>=10 and vPos <=60 ) )then
                RGB <= "11111110";
            else
                RGB <= "00000011";  
            end if;
        else
            RGB <= "00000000";
        end if;

    end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Did it work in simulation?

Comment: Are you synchronizing inputs (if any) to your local clock domain? You need to feed inputs that asynchronous to your clock through a chain of at least two flip flops before using it or you get metastability issues which look like severe jitter.

Comment: Also (clk25'event and clk25 ='1') are deprecated for rising_edge(clk25) and falling_edge(clk25)

Comment: @BrianDrummond I added the simulation result. In the following site, it is written that whole line should be 31.777557100298us
http://tinyvga.com/vga-timing/640x480@60Hz. In the simulation, it is 56.32us.

Comment: Do you get any warnings at compilation time, especially timing? And from the link to the forum: Have you replaced your clock with a stable clock? Else, you'll never get a good result. Without reading the datasheet: Is there an alternative clock? Like onchip clock from the spartan 3 that you can use?

Comment: What is this line `if(videoOn <= '1') then` supposed to do?

Comment: If the RGB output bits are all 1, why is the color yellow? Please show us your video interface circuit.

Comment: @BruceAbbott yes ...that would suggest the blue channel has gone astray ... which may also explain why RGB=X"03" (present in sim) looks black. Would only take moments to try a different colour... Doesn't explain the timing problems in sim or anywhere else though.

Comment: if(videoOn <= '1') then ,  when I changed this line with '=' the problem is solved actually. @BruceAbbott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comments you say that after changing `if(videoOn <= '1')` to `if(videoOn = '1')` "the problem is solved". But why?

In your original code the the video was *always* on, so the background color extended into the blanking area. I suspect the monitor then took that value (which should be 0 V during horizontal blanking) as the black reference level for that channel. This would make that color (blue in this case) appear black on screen. It would also remove its contribution from the color of the squares, explaining why the squares appeared yellow when they should have been white.